# Qt5 - how to find the headers files using make?

Tags: makefile, header, qt5

I have a issue for mac OsX

before, I was using Qt4 which installed itself in /Library/Frameworks for all Users.
So, I had a generic makefile for my all my Osx Users... using this informations.

But since, Qt5 asks you to install itself where you want  with the version number... 
usually somewhere like : /Users/myname/Qt5.3.2/...

What can I use or how can i find the Headers filse to compile my program using makefile (no Cmake, Qmake ...) without asking my user : where did you install your Qt5 frameworks ?

I have tried to use *.pc in the Qt5.x.x/clang64/lib/pkgconfig directory but they seem to be wrong.

pkg-config --libs Qt5Core (ok) :
    `-F/Users/myname/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib -framework QtCore`

pkg-config --cflags Qt5Core (not ok) :
    `-I/Users/myname/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/include/QtCore -I/Users/myname/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/include`

but I need something like :
    `-F/Users/myname/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib -I/Users/myname/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers`

anyone have an idea ... or this problem ?
I found nothing interesting on google, because most people using Cmake or Qmake and i can't.

note : I have no problem on linux because i'm using pkg-config information.

thanks

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug with whoever is providing that `.pc` file since it is wrong. But if you know the include path from the lib path you can always just manually replace values from one to get the other.

Comment: Yes I can manage a script to do so but I was wondering if there was a Official way such as a variable: QT_DIR_INSTALL that wasn't in Qt5 documentation and I wasn't aware.

Comment: If there is I'm not aware of one either, I don't use Qt at all. Does a `qt5-config` script exist at this point (I wouldn't expect it but it might)?

Comment: AND pkg-config is not native on Mac